# I can't find configuration file -> MySQL 8.0.21

Tags: mysql

I wanted to set up a local database in MySQLWorkbench but I have no configuration. Can it be generated somehow?
[image]

Comment: Mysqlworkbench is a client tool, it has nothing to do with your mysql's config file.

Comment: as far as I know, with Mysqlworkbench I can create new databases as long as I connect to mysql. My goal is to create a base, how to achieve it? because when I login to mysql by console and use this command `mysql> CREATE DATABASE my-datadabse` i get `->` and nothing happens ... :/

Comment: You are mixing up things. Yes, you can create databases with workbench. However, the mysql config file applies to the mysql server, not to workbench. As for the cli use: you need to terminate the statement with ;

Comment: you have right, thank you :)